# Powershell sort from line 2

Tags: powershell, sort-object

I want to sort a .txt document, so that the first line stays on top, and the rest gets sorted by numbers.

I currently have the following, but it removes the first line, and the sorting isn't correct, since the numbers are e.g. 72, 2, 51, 100, 201, 5 etc. 
so it sorts it like 100, 2, 201, 5, 51, 72.

And I wish to have it sorted like 2, 5, 51, 72, 100, 201

```
$emptyLine = Get-Content C:\Path\Document.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1
$emptyLine | Sort-Object | Out-File C:\Path\Document.txt
```

I know this is possible in Notepad++ but the machine that needs to do the sorting isn't allowed to install anything new.

I'm very open if for any solution, that doesn't require me to install a new piece of software.

The machine is Windows 10 Pro x64.

[Current Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcC4q.png)

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLqy2.png)

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyHyL.png)

```html
No        Tool_Name        Tool_Part
72        10        1      9.    1
43        36        3      29.     1
102       34        1      1.7     1
600       33        1      3.      1
76        3         1      5.3     1
75        3         1      5.5     1
251       2         3      3.      1
73        10        1      5.3     1
50        36        3      15.9    1
64        2         1      6.      1
```

(Posted as HTML snippet, to make formatting more beautiful)

Comment: Can you provide the sample input?

Comment: Heine, Welcome to Stackoverflow, to get better and quicker results on your questions (and save the answering people some time), I recommend you add (input/desired/current) listings in text format rather than pictures.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Oh yeah, makes sense to me! Sorry about that, I will keep that in mind!

Comment: @Heine, I have changed my answer in respect to the given source table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take advantage of multi-value assignment and store the output from `Get-Content` in two variables, then sort only the second:

```
$First,$Rest = Get-Content C:\Path\Document.txt
@($First; $Rest |Sort-Object) |Set-Content C:\Path\Document.txt
```

In the scenario above, PowerShell will assign the first line to `$First` and the rest to `$Rest`

If you need `Sort-Object` to sort by the first part of a string property as if it was an integer, you could do it like this:

```
@($First; $Rest |Sort-Object {(-split $_)[0] -as [int]}) |Set-Content C:\Path\Document.txt
```

Comment: I think that the issue is that the list needs to be sorted on the integer value of the first column and not the whole line (string)...

Comment: This is what works the best! Thank you!
Is it possible to make it recognize the lack of 002 instead of 2?

Comment: Sorry, completely missed that part @HeineKristensen - updated the answer

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You might use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6), skip the header and than do some tricks to rebuild your table but you might also consider using the [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) to convert your table directly into objects:

```
$List = Get-Content C:\Path\Document.txt | ConvertFrom-SourceTable
```

Unfortunately the numbers in the first column appear to be left aligned, if they where right aligned (as in the final results of this answer), the `ConvertFrom-SourceTable` cmdlet would have automatically evaluated the first '`No`' column into numbers.
This means that you will need to transfer the first column into integers yourself to be able to sort them as suggested. You can do this by using the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) and creating a calculated property:

```
Select-Object @{n='No'; e={[Int]$_.No}}, Tool_Name, Tool_Part
```

After that, you can simply use [`sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-6) to sort it:

```
Sort-Object No
```

Putting an example together:

```
ConvertFrom-SourceTable '
    No        Tool_Name        Tool_Part
    72        10        1      9.      1
    43        36        3      29.     1
    102       34        1      1.7     1
    600       33        1      3.      1
    76        3         1      5.3     1
    75        3         1      5.5     1
    251       2         3      3.      1
    73        10        1      5.3     1
    50        36        3      15.9    1
    64        2         1      6.      1
' | Select-Object @{n='No'; e={[Int]$_.No}}, Tool_Name, Tool_Part | Sort-Object No
```

This example will result in:

```
 No Tool_Name Tool_Part
 -- --------- ---------
 43 36        29.     1
 50 36        15.9    1
 64 2         6.      1
 72 10        9.      1
 73 10        5.3     1
 75 3         5.5     1
 76 3         5.3     1
102 34        1.7     1
251 2         3.      1
600 33        3.      1
```

As it is unclear whether the column between `Tool_Name` and `Tool_Part` belongs to either of the column (because `Tool_Part` could be either left aligned or right aligned), you might provide a ruler to the `ConvertFrom-SourceTable` yourself to settle this:

```
ConvertFrom-SourceTable -Ruler '---       -----------      ---------' '
No        Tool_Name        Tool_Part
72        10        1      9.      1
43        36        3      29.     1
102       34        1      1.7     1
600       33        1      3.      1
76        3         1      5.3     1
75        3         1      5.5     1
251       2         3      3.      1
73        10        1      5.3     1
50        36        3      15.9    1
64        2         1      6.      1
' | Select-Object @{n='No'; e={[Int]$_.No}}, Tool_Name, Tool_Part | Sort-Object No
```

Result:

```
 No Tool_Name   Tool_Part
 -- ---------   ---------
 43 36        3 29.     1
 50 36        3 15.9    1
 64 2         1 6.      1
 72 10        1 9.      1
 73 10        1 5.3     1
 75 3         1 5.5     1
 76 3         1 5.3     1
102 34        1 1.7     1
251 2         3 3.      1
600 33        1 3.      1
```

Comment: This is really great, but I cannot format the table, since it is a list that some CNC machine is reading from, and it generates the formatting of the table itself :(. But Thanks, I will most likely be needing this in the future!